# pandas, grouping and aggregating

Tags: python, pandas

I have grouped a dataframe:

```
rwp_initial.df.loc[rwp_initial.df.sample_name=='sma_initial'].groupby(by=['sample_name','pH','salt','column'])['concentration'].plot(marker = 'o', rot=30)
```

and get following output:

```
sample_name  pH   salt  column
sma_initial  5.7  50    5         Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                        6         Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                  100   7         Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                        8         Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                  200   9         Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                        10        Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                  400   11        Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
                        12        Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
```

[image]

i would like to take the mean within each pH and salt concentration. The columns are just the same sample measured two times. If i use `aggregate(np.mean)` the average of all datapoints of one column is calculated.

This figure maybe highlights the data points i would like to take the average of ( i would like to average along the rows):

```
rwp_initial.df.loc[rwp_initial.df.sample_name=='sma_initial'].groupby(by=['sample_name','pH','salt'])['concentration'].plot(marker = 'o', rot=30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the answer:

```
grp_initial = rwp_initial.df.loc[rwp_initial.df.sample_name=='sma_initial'].groupby(by=['sample_name','pH','salt']).concentration

for grp, val in grp_initial:
    print(val.groupby(level='row').aggregate(np.mean))
```

works